# Problems with encoding during buffer overflow exploit

Tags: c, python-3.x, character-encoding, stack, buffer-overflow

I am on Ubuntu Linux 16.04/Intel with ASLR turned off.

The below programme is exploited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *name)
{
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, name);
    printf("Welcome %s\n", buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   func(argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

It is built with.

```
$ gcc buf.c -o buf -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2
```

I can successfully overflow the buffer and overwrite the return address when using 7-bit characters (?) like below.

```
gdb-peda$ run $(python3 -c 'print("\x41" * 108)')
```

[image]

However, it doesn't work correctly when I try to insert an 8-bit character (?).

```
gdb-peda$ run $(python3 -c 'print("\xc0" * 108)')
```

[image]

There seems to be some kind of UTF-8 encoding on the way, so `\xc0` becomes `\xc3\x80`.

I tried running

```
gdb-peda$ run $(python3 -c 'print(("\xc0".encode("latin1") * 108))')
```

This does something messed up.. In any case, the return address is not overwritten successfully.

[image]

Stuck and any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Python by default encodes strings by `sys.stdout.encoding` before writing the bytes. You can directly write bytes to `sys.stdout.buffer` to avoid encoding:

```
run $(python3 -c '__import__("sys").stdout.buffer.write(b"\xc0" * 108)')
```

What's happening when you do `print("\xc0".encode("latin1") * 108)` (Equivalenty just `print(b"\xc0" * 108)`) is that it's printing `b'\xc0\xc0...\xc0\xc0'` (The literal bytes `b`, `'`, `\`, `x`, ... or `0x62`, `0x27`, `0x5C`, `0x78`, ...)